# Can Windows 7 Home run active directory

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, active-directory

I'm working on an asp.net website that uses active directory authentication on login.  Until now, I've been developing this site via a machine at work, which has active directory setup, but I now need to work on this project from home via my Windows 7 Home edition machine.

From what I've read though, active directory isn't available on home edition.  Does anyone know of a way to setup AD on a home edition computer?  Or know of some other software that will simulate what I'm looking to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AD will not work 'out of the box' for windows home editions. Perhaps third party software/hacks can enable this but that seems like over-kill, since setting up AD to enable from-home developing might not be your best option.

While I'm not aware of the possibilities of 'faking AD' for your ASP.NET application, you might as well rebuild te logging mechanism.

If you haven't already, you really should ask the network administrator from work if it's possible to connect through RDP/VPN. This way you can connect to your computer at work and just use it from there.